# SQL first to CAST the COUNT as INT then SUM the COUNT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have data in my SQL Server database as below.

```
descr   code
11200   BM
11201   BM
11202   BM
11203   BM
11204   BM
11205   BM
11300   EN
11301   EN
11302   EN
```

my query is as below

```
SELECT DISTINCT descr, code
    , CAST(COUNT(code) over (partition by code) as int) as codecount
FROM category 
WHERE descr IN('11200','11201','11300') AND code IN ('BM','BM','EN') 
GROUP BY descr, code 
ORDER BY descr asc, code asc
```

after my query is executed, my data is shown as below

```
descr   code    codecount
11200    BM         2
11201    BM         2                               
11300    EN         1
```

My question is, can I SUM my `codecount` after I `cast` and `count` it? Example as below

```
descr   code    codecount    sum
11200    BM         2         3 
11201    BM         2         3           
11300    EN         1         3
```

The SUM value is calculated by summing up the codecount column where codecount with the same code will only run one time, based on my question, notice that I have 2 code with value of BM and 1 code with value of EN, so the sum shall be 3, it is to ignore value that are having same code.

How can I do this?

Comment: varchar value then cast it to int in order to count, correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: you can count strings, no need to cast to int first. If there are no NULL codes, use COUNT(*). It's unclear what the sum is for. Is it the grand total of all rows?

Comment: Your query won't work unless you use `[desc]` instead of `desc` as its a reserved word.

Comment: @DaleK `codecount` column is to show the count of selected `code`, if you notice in my question, there are two BM and one EN, so when i count it, `codecount` for BM will be 2 and for EN will be 1.

@SQLRaptor the SUM is used to count the grand total of `codecount` row

Comment: no need for distinct either. You group by desc and code, and select both so your select expressions are unique.

Comment: @DaleK sry, wrong presentation of question, that data is after my query is done. Edited the question.

Comment: @SQLRaptor alright, i edited the question with the details

Comment: @DaleK Assuming i ignore all other same `code` values, sum is calculated by the selected 2 BM and 1 EN. So it shall be 3.  and if i never cast, yes results return, but when i want to SUM it up `SUM(COUNT(code) over (partition by code)) as codecount` , it shows error: Windowed functions cannot be used in the context of another windowed function or aggregate.

Comment: Its still not clear where the value 3 comes from, please clarify in your question, not in the comments.

Comment: @DaleK see my edited question

Comment: Hopefully you know understand the reason why you need your question to be clear and complete from the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your current sample data all you need is a row count, because the `GROUP BY` isn't doing anything. Also your `CAST` isn't required, the result of `COUNT` is already an `INT`. The following query returns the expected results:

```
declare @Category table ([desc] varchar(32), code varchar(32));

insert into @Category ([desc], code)
    values
    ('11200', 'BM'),
    ('11201', 'BM'),
    ('11202', 'BM'),
    ('11203', 'BM'),
    ('11204', 'BM'),
    ('11205', 'BM'),
    ('11300', 'EN'),
    ('11301', 'EN'),
    ('11302', 'EN');

SELECT [desc], code
  , COUNT(code) OVER (PARTITION BY code) as codecount
  , COUNT(code) OVER () as totalcodecount
FROM @Category 
ORDER BY [desc] asc, code asc;
```

Returns:

```
desc    code    codecount   totalcodecount
------------------------------------------
11200   BM      6           9
11201   BM      6           9
11202   BM      6           9
11203   BM      6           9
11204   BM      6           9
11205   BM      6           9
11300   EN      3           9
11301   EN      3           9
11302   EN      3           9
```

PS: This is the recommended way to present a question in future with DDL/DML statements allowing someone to copy and paste and start testing without having to type all your sample data in.

Comment: Thanks for the help, as you mention, result of count is int, meaning that after every count, it will change the type to INT?

Comment: The `codecount` column in the resultset is an `int` - thats how it works.

Answer (score 1):

*Not tested as you didn't provide DDL / sample data INSERTs*

You can't nest window functions, so you'll have to separate it with a CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT [desc], [code]
        , COUNT(*) over (partition by [code]) as codecount
    FROM category 
    WHERE [desc] IN ('11200','11201','11300') AND [code] IN ('BM','BM','EN') 
    GROUP BY [desc], [code] 
)
SELECT *
    , SUM(codecount) OVER() AS GrandTotal
FROM CTE
ORDER BY [desc] asc, [code] asc;
```